css has function not working with not has element selector
I have the following element structure:
<div class="general">

    <div class="general-container">

        <div class="general-grid">

            <div class="general-wrapper"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

I'm trying to not display the general div when the general-wrapper is not having any child elements.
So first tried this:
.general-wrapper:not(:has(*)) {
background-color:red;
}

Which works.
Then this:
.general-container:has( .general-wrapper ) {
background-color:green;
}

Which also works.
But when I combine them it doesn't.
.general-container:has( .general-wrapper:not(:has(*) ) ) {
display:none; // it does display, while it should not :(
}

codepen link:
https://codepen.io/Redox-FGL/pen/LYKgZzq
What I'm doing wrong or not getting?
Note: not looking for a solution with empty, there are more variables here and empty is not working. Need to check on child elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#syntax: "The :has() pseudo-class cannot be nested within another :has()."

Thnx @C3roe for this reference, this explains a lot!

Do this instead:


.general-container:not(:has(.general-wrapper > *)) {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
<div class="general">

  <div class="general-container">

    <div class="general-grid">

      <div class="general-wrapper">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>




Can you show that this works? Perhaps add one that DOES have content

Can confirm,I was 2 seconds away from the same answer. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oNraLQK

Thnx! This work

You can set general-container to display none and then set it to display block, for example, if the wrapper has content.


/* don't display general when general-wrapper has no children */


/* so display general when it does have children,otherwise display: none */

.general {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}

.general:has(.general-wrapper > *) {
  display: block;
}
<h2>WITHOUT CONTENT</h2>
<div class="general">

  <div class="general-container">

    <div class="general-grid">

      <div class="general-wrapper">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<h2>WITH CONTENT</h2>
<div class="general">

  <div class="general-container">

    <div class="general-grid">

      <div class="general-wrapper">
        <div></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>



